# android studio for each loop causing crash with uncaught exeption

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio

On the for each loop in this android studio app I'm not catching any exceptions but whenever the page containing it loads it crashes I cant figure out why. any help will be greatly appreciated

this for each loop goes throught and compares the Booleans for what day of the week it is to the date for mat in the switch statement above and then display which pills you need to take in an alert on that specific day

I'm very new to programming so please have mercy

```
package com.example.josep.loginactivity;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {



    //private TextView mTextMessage;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    setTitle("Pill List");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, PillListActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    setTitle("Add a New Pill");
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(Home.this, AddPill.class);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        //mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
        BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
         int mine;
        switch (day) {
            case Calendar.SUNDAY:
                mine =6;
                break;
            case Calendar.MONDAY:
                mine =0;
                break;

            case Calendar.TUESDAY:
                mine=1;
                break;

            case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
                mine=2;
                break;

            case Calendar.THURSDAY:
                mine=3;
                break;
            case Calendar.FRIDAY:
                mine=4;
                break;

            case Calendar.SATURDAY:
                mine=5;
                break;
        }
        String set = "";



        DBhelper dbPill = new DBhelper(this);
        List<pillModel> pillList = dbPill.getAllPills();

        for(pillModel p:  pillList)
        {
            Boolean[]find = p.getDays();
            for (int i =0; i<find.length; i++)
            if(find[i])
            {
                set += p.getName() ;
                set += " ";
            }
        }

/*

       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("today you need to take "+ set);

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //perform any action
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thank YOu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


*/
        //creating alert dialog
        /*AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
*/




    }
}
```

DBhelper class

```
package com.example.josep.loginactivity;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


        // Database Name
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "motherDB2";
        // Database Version
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

        // Table Names
        //private static final String TABLE_POLL = "Poll";
        //private static final String TABLE_VOTER = "voter";
        private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";
       private static final String TABLE_PILL = "pill";
      // private static final String TABLE_APPT = "appt";



        //  create  Tables for poll, voter, and user
        //private static final String CREATE_TABLE_POLL = "CREATE TABLE "  + TABLE_POLL+ " (CANDIDATEID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FIRSTNAME TEXT, LASTNAME TEXT, PARTY TEXT, STATE TEXT, ELECTIONYEAR INTEGER)";
        //private static final String CREATE_TABLE_VOTER = "CREATE TABLE "  + TABLE_VOTER+ " (VOTERID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FIRSTNAME TEXT, LASTNAME TEXT, STATE TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, ZIPCODE TEXT)";
       // private static final String CREATE_TABLE_APPT = "CREATE TABLE "  + TABLE_APPT+ " (APPTID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, EMAIL TEXT, DATE TEXT, COMMENT TEXT)";
        private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USER = "CREATE TABLE "  + TABLE_USER+ " (USERID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, EMAIL TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT)";
       private static final String CREATE_TABLE_PILL = "CREATE TABLE "  + TABLE_PILL+
               " (PILLID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, PILL TEXT, DOSE INTEGER, MONDAY BOOLEAN, TUESDAY BOOLEAN, WEDNESDAY BOOLEAN, THURSDAY BOOLEAN, FRIDAY BOOLEAN, SATURDAY BOOLEAN, SUNDAY BOOLEAN, ACTIVE BOOLEAN)";

        public DBhelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }




    @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)
        {
            // creating required tables
            //sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_POLL);
            //sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_VOTER);
           sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_PILL);
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USER);
           // sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_DEAL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            // on upgrade drop older tables
            //sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_POLL);
            //sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_VOTER);
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER);
           sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PILL);
           // sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_APPT);
            // create new tables
            onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
        }

        // ------------------------ "POLL" table methods ----------------//

    public boolean insertPill(pillModel pill)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("PILL", pill.getName());
        values.put("DOSE", pill.getDoses());
        values.put("MONDAY", pill.isMonday());
        values.put("TUESDAY", pill.isTuesday());
        values.put("WEDNESDAY", pill.isWednesday());
        values.put("THURSDAY", pill.isThursday());
        values.put("FRIDAY", pill.isFriday());
        values.put("SATURDAY", pill.isSaturday());
        values.put("SUNDAY", pill.isSunday());
        values.put("ACTIVE", pill.isActive());

        long result  = db.insert(TABLE_PILL, null, values );
        if(result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;

    }

    public String getPillInfo(pillModel pill){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "Select PILL , DOSE, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY,"+
                "SATURDAY ,SUNDAY , ACTIVE  FROM " + TABLE_PILL ;
        Cursor resultSet = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if(resultSet.getCount()== 0)
            return null;
        else
            return  query;
    }
    public List<pillModel> getAllPills()
    {
        List<pillModel> pillList = new ArrayList<pillModel>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_PILL;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor resultSet = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (resultSet.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                pillModel pill = new pillModel();
                pill.setPillID((resultSet.getInt(resultSet.getColumnIndex("PILLID"))));
                pill.setName((resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("PILL"))));
                pill.setDoses((resultSet.getInt(resultSet.getColumnIndex("DOSE"))));
                pill.setMonday(Boolean.parseBoolean((resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("MONDAY")))));
                pill.setTuesday(Boolean.parseBoolean((resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("TUESDAY")))));
                pill.setWednesday(Boolean.parseBoolean((resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("WEDNESDAY")))));
                pill.setThursday(Boolean.parseBoolean((resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("THURSDAY")))));
                pill.setFriday(Boolean.parseBoolean((resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("FRIDAY")))));
                pill.setSaturday(Boolean.parseBoolean((resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("SATURDAY")))));
                pill.setSunday(Boolean.parseBoolean((resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("SUNDAY")))));
                pill.setActive(Boolean.parseBoolean((resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("ACTIVE")))));

                // adding to poll list
                pillList.add(pill);
            } while (resultSet.moveToNext());
        }
        return pillList;
    }

        public boolean insertUser(userModel user)
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("EMAIL", user.getEmail());
            values.put("PASSWORD", user.getPass());
            long result  = db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values );
            if(result == -1)
                return false;
            else
                return true;

        }
        public Boolean getLoginInfo(userModel user){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            String query = "Select EMAIL, PASSWORD FROM " + TABLE_USER + " WHERE EMAIL = '"+user.getEmail() +"' AND PASSWORD= '"+user.getPass()+"'";
            Cursor resultSet = db.rawQuery(query, null);
            if(resultSet.getCount()== 0)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
        public String getDose(String pill)
        {
            String query = "Select PILL FROM " + TABLE_PILL + " WHERE PILL = '"+pill +"'";
            return query;
        }
       public void addDose(String pill){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            String dose = "Select DOSE FROM " + TABLE_PILL + " WHERE PILL = '"+pill +"'";
            int house = Integer.parseInt(dose);
            house+=1;
            String mind =""+house;
            String query = "Update DOSE FROM " + TABLE_PILL + " SET DOSE = '"+mind +"'";

        }

    public void romoveDose(String pill){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String dose = "Select DOSE FROM " + TABLE_PILL + " WHERE PILL = '"+pill +"'";
        int house = Integer.parseInt(dose);
        house-=1;
        String mind =""+house;
        String query = "Update " + TABLE_PILL + " SET DOSE = '"+mind +"'";
        //db.update("Update"+TABLE_PILL+ " SET DOSE="+ mind + "WHERE PILL="+pill);
    }
    }
```

pill model class

```
package com.example.josep.loginactivity;

public class pillModel {


    private String name;
    private int Doses;
    private int pillID;
    private boolean monday;
    private boolean tuesday;
    private boolean wednesday;
    private boolean thursday;
    private boolean friday;
    private boolean saturday;
    private boolean sunday;
    private boolean active;

    public void setPillID(int id)
    {
        this.pillID = id;
    }
    public int getpillID()
    {
        return pillID;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setDoses(int Doeses)
    {
        this.Doses = Doses;
    }

    public Integer getDoses()
    {
        return Doses;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public boolean isSunday() {
        return sunday;
    }

    public void setSunday(boolean sunday) {
        this.sunday = sunday;
    }

    public boolean isSaturday() {
        return saturday;
    }

    public void setSaturday(boolean saturday) {
        this.saturday = saturday;
    }

    public boolean isFriday() {
        return friday;
    }

    public void setFriday(boolean friday) {
        this.friday = friday;
    }

    public boolean isThursday() {
        return thursday;
    }

    public void setThursday(boolean thursday) {
        this.thursday = thursday;
    }

    public boolean isWednesday() {
        return wednesday;
    }

    public void setWednesday(boolean wednesday) {
        this.wednesday = wednesday;
    }

    public boolean isTuesday() {
        return tuesday;
    }

    public void setTuesday(boolean tuesday) {
        this.tuesday = tuesday;
    }

    public boolean isMonday() {
        return monday;
    }

    public void setMonday(boolean monday) {
        this.monday = monday;
    }

    public Boolean[]  getDays()
    {
        Boolean[]Days =new Boolean[6];
        String house = getName();
        if(isActive() && isMonday())
        {
            Days[0]=true;

        }
        if(isActive() && isTuesday())
        {
            Days[1]=true;

        }
        if(isActive() && isWednesday())
        {
            Days[2]=true;

        }
        if(isActive() && isThursday())
        {
            Days[3]=true;
        }
        if(isActive() && isFriday())
        {
            Days[4]=true;

        }
        if(isActive() && isSaturday())
        {
            Days[5]=true;

        }
        if(isActive() && isSunday())
        {
            Days[6]=true;

        }
        return Days;
    }

    public pillModel() {

    }

    public pillModel(String name, int Doses, boolean monday, boolean tuesday, boolean wednesday, boolean thursday,
                     boolean friday, boolean saturday, boolean sunday, boolean active) {

        this.name = name;
        this.Doses = Doses;
        this.monday = monday;
        this.tuesday = tuesday;
        this.wednesday = wednesday;
        this.thursday = thursday;
        this.friday = friday;
        this.saturday = saturday;
        this.sunday = sunday;
        this.active = active;
    }
}
```